# Pulling a hashed username from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-password-hash

I'm working on a project where both the username and password need to be hashed with Argon2. I'm not having any trouble hashing them both in the registration and inserting them into the database, but I'm unable to pull  the information for the login. Here is my login script:

```
<?php  session_start(); ?>
<?php
include 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$submittedUser = $_POST['username'];
$submittedPass = $_POST['password'];
$encrypteduser = password_hash($submittedUser, PASSWORD_ARGON2I);

$con=mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM users Where username =?")) {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $encrypteduser);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$username = $row['username'];
$password = $row['password'];
}
if (password_verify($submittedUser, $username) && password_verify($submittedPass, $password))
{
$_SESSION['user']=$username; 

echo "<script> location.href='index.php'; </script>";
        exit;   
}
else
{
 echo "<script> location.href='login.php'; </script>";
        exit;   
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

My current theory is that the hash being generated and stored in `$encrypteduser` does not match the one in the database. That would explain why no result is being pulled. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: password_hash generates a new salt each time so it wont match, why do you need to hash the username? You could go with a digest hash like sha or instead encrypt it and use the aes functions in sql.. but protecting the username is ott imo

Comment: why on earth would you hash a username?

Comment: The project I'm working on is a messaging service where all the information is encrypted (usernames, passwords, messages.) Everything is stored and run from a raspberry pi so that the only way for every message to be accessed is through physical or SSH access to the server.

Comment: Hashing != Encryption

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Jynx..

Comment: I wonder how many more times the OP will be told that hashing isn't encryption, besides the answer.

Comment: Maybe a few more time and I'll fully understand. Haven't had my coffee today.

Comment: If you're using a messaging service and encrypting usernames won't users messaging each other see the encrypted username, causing a gratuitous amount of issues?

Comment: Just out of curiousity; what are the column lengths?

Comment: 255 @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @EvanEdwards ok. I edited for clarity btw.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thank you. Looks like I'll end up leaving them in plaintext for now.

Comment: @EvanEdwards You're welcome Evan. Btw, I did try something like that before. It is possible but it's a bit tricky. I just don't know where the script I made is *lol!* It's been a few years.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Let me know if you ever find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not encrypt, it hashes:

```
$encrypteduser = password_hash($submittedUser, PASSWORD_ARGON2I);
```

I.e., it's one way. You (theoretically) can never get the original text back from it. It will also generate a different result every time you run it. As a result, you'll never be able to run a query with a `WHERE` clause to pick out one matching user. Rather, you'd have to iterate over every user in the system, running `password_verify()` against each of them.

So... don't do that. Leave the username in plain text so that you can benefit from the database index.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do cannot be done because having the username stored in clear is exactly what allows to you determine what exact credentials (i.e. table row) you need to validate against.

Imagine you tried anyway. You want to validate `john.doe`. You would have to loop on every stored username hash, grab the corresponding salt so you can calculate the hash with `john.doe` and current row salt and then compare both username hashes. If there's no match, go to next row... until you eventually get a match and can finally determine what password hash to check. All this, with al algorithm specifically designed to be *slow*. Go figure.

Comment: About your opening; that's false; I've done it before and can't remember how I did it exactly. I just don't remember where that script is. It's tricky but it can be done.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The only workaround I can think is having an alternative field to sign in (email, numeric ID...). Just think of passwords themselves: there's surely a user who chose `password` or `1234` and the point is crackers not being able to know which one unless they verify every password on the stolen table.